# Customer email using .online tld is being rejected

Tags: opayo

I'm using DotNetKit 1.2.6.5 and `SagePayIntegration.Validation()` is rejecting a customer email that uses the new .online domain (eg: foo@bar.online) with

> CustomerEMail is invalid.

Is this fixed in 1.2.6.7 or is the source code for SagePay.IntegrationKit.DotNet.dll available somewhere so I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite access to the source code (many thanks to @DavidG) SagePay Support have confirmed that the actual Gateway does not support all these new domains - so even if I modified the DotNetKit it would still be rejected by the Gateway.

SagePay support were very helpful but ultimately the

> "... email domain foo@bar.online is not yet supported on our gateway.
>   We run development sprints continuously and although there are some
>   domains we may not yet support, we look to in future, dependent on
>   impact and demand..."

Comment: Oh my, that is kinda crazy. I guess it means I can't order anything using my public email address... I don't understand why they would restrict the domains at all.

Answer (score 0):

The SagePay Integration Kit uses this regex to validate email addresses:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,4})\b
```

Which does unfortunately not allow extra long TLDs. Fortunately I have the source code for the kit and I've added it to my GitHub account (along with a bug fix which is why I had to get it in the first place as SagePay are not updating it). You can find it here:

https://github.com/WiredUK/SagePay.IntegrationKit

And the Regex you need to edit is this file:

https://github.com/WiredUK/SagePay.IntegrationKit/blob/801f61cf965c391a98a025aa632949719084cef0/ApiRegex.cs

For info, you need to edit the very last part of the expression from `2,4` (which matches 2 to 4 characters in the TLD) to allow more, for example `2,30`.

**Edit:** And just because I can, I [opened an issue and fixed it](https://github.com/WiredUK/SagePay.IntegrationKit/issues/1).

Comment: Great, hope it works for you. I wonder who downvoted this though, strange!

Comment: Ye, I thought that was odd too. BTW: Is this source based on 1.2.6.7 ?

Comment: The version number wasn't given to me with the source code, but they did say it was the most recent one and that no further updates would be made to it by them.